# GetElementById without id and name HOW?

Tags: c#, browser

I need to click the button "Add" in the post new wordpress form, this button is to add tags to the post , the trouble is that button don't have the value and id propertie. Is just like that

the html for the button

```
input type="button" class="button tagadd" value="Add" tabindex="3"
```

my tries

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button tagadd").InvokeMember("click");

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Add").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Can you not add an `id` attribute to the button?

Comment: how can I do that?
I'm using the webbrowser control

Comment: So the HTML is not in your control?

Comment: sorry i don't get it. I use the websbrowser control to open a wordpress blog, go to new postpage,  then I set the title, the content and then the tags, but to add tags I have to click the add little button with no id and name.

Comment: Ahhh... that's a good bit of context missing from your question. How about editing your question and adding it?

Answer (score 4):

> "GetElementById without id"

:-)

*Unless you can change the markup for the button*

What you need now is to traverse the entire DOM and look for a button in a known place. I'd suggest adding jquery if not already exist to be able for easier dom manipulation/search.

If you add jquery you could do something like `$(".tagadd").click()`

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing

```
webBrowser1.document.getElementsByClassName("tagadd")
```

EDIT: Here is a script to create the getElementsByClassName function if it's not available http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

There is also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx  but I've never used it.

Comment: not working, it give me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @robert in this case, it's probably because `webBrowser1` probably isn't defined. Try just using `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Do you have Firebug or the IE debug tools installed?

Comment: I don't get the getElementsByClassName I have to add something like using something;

Comment: I don't think everything supports getElementsByClassName, I updated my answer to include a link where you can generate the function.

Answer (score 0):

- Add an ID. Even if you're dynamically generating the buttons this should be trivial.
- If you're using jQuery,

  $('.tagadd')

will return a collection of everything with the `tagadd` class applied. You can further filter this by the other classes (`button`, etc)

- Use this:

  onload=function(){
  if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
      document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
      {
          var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\s)" + className + "(?:$|\s)");
          var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
          var results = [];

  ```
      var element;
      for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
          var elementClass = element.className;
          if (elementClass
  ```

  && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 
  && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                  results.push(element);
          }

  ```
      return results;
  }
  ```

  }
  }

and another

1. Some browsers provide the method `getElementsByClassName()` which lets you select by class without using jQuery (which is a bit heavy if this is all you need). I haven't tested this so I'm not sure how widely it's supported.
2. Did I mention that you should give everything an ID?

Answer (score 0):

use TagName isteed for example

```
var elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            if (elem.GetAttribute("class") == "button tagadd")
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```